# объединить [html] и [html5]

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

предлагаю [html5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5) сделать синонимом [html](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[html5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5) - это метка для вопросов по новым возможностям html5. Не надо её объединять с [html](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html).

Comment: Этим «новым возможностям» уже больше десяти лет, какой смысл?

Comment: @andreymal, не всем. Смысл как и обычно у меток - разделение. У нас же есть пачка меток по версия Си++ и пачка меток по версиям винды, да и по остальным технологиям так же. Так чем не угодил html?